# what other midi controller could I connect with YAMAHA TG55

Tags: guitar, midi

I have a Tone Generator Yamaha TG55 Midi. I want to play music with other midi controller like a guitar or other things but I´ve been seeing that a guitar midi is an expencil solution. I see that there are PS3 guitar for playing rock band that it has midi output (5-pins) but I need to know if is possible to play with it.

Could you help me?
thanks in advance
PS: what other midi controler can I use to connect with the yamaha tg-55

Comment: What "other things"? Keyboards? [Hamsters](https://courses.cit.cornell.edu/eceprojectsland/STUDENTPROJ/2002to2003/lil2/)?

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of MIDI controllers.

Most MIDI controllers are keyboards. If you're looking for a guitar-like controller and you're on a tight budget, your choices are rather limited. A PS3 guitar controller can be adapted for MIDI, but there are better options. Look for the "You Rock Guitar" controller. They're sold new for about $250 US. If you win the lottery, check out the Starr Labs Ztar. You may also be able to find older equipment on the used market. The Yamaha G-10 was a "pro" solution in the 80s. The Casio DG-20 was a bit more toy-ish, but had strings and MIDI output.

Guitar-to-MIDI may be another option but it works differently. It uses a hexaphonic pickup on a real guitar. A converter box translates the detected pitches to MIDI. Your cheapest options here would be to find a Roland GI-10 or Roland GI-20 on the used market. Casio also made the PG-380. It was a real guitar with a built-in converter and MIDI output.

There are percussion controllers, pad controllers, accordion controllers, and all sorts of outlandish things out there!

Answer (score 0):

anything with a midi out port.  So pretty much any keyboard.  I've never messed with a midi guitar, but if it's got midi then it'll work.  My guess is the PS3 guitar doesn't come with midi out as there's an adapter being sold for it to do midi: [http://www.amazon.com/PlayStation-Rock-Band-MIDI-PRO-3/dp/B0042B3EOM](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0042B3EOM)
If it is standard midi out it'll work.  But not sure what range of notes, etc you'll get from the thing.  So your real question might be "can the ps3 guitar generate midi out"...